# Why doesn't the DataGrid correctly rebind to its source list after I've sorted the grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

**Background**

I have a `DataGrid` that doesn't appear to display the data correctly after I remove an item from its data source list when the data grid is sorted.

This is my grid:

```
   <DataGrid Name="fileGrid" 
              SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="fileGrid_SelectionChanged" PreviewKeyDown="PreviewKeyDownHandler">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- other columns removed for brevity -->

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Installation"  SortMemberPath="Customer.CompanyName" Width="*"
                x:Name="columnCompanyName" 
                Binding="{Binding Path=Customer.CompanyName}"
                IsReadOnly="True">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I can delete an item from the list, e.g. by calling

```
    public void DeleteAndRebind(PanelData panelData)
    {
        _panelDataList.Remove(panelData);
        Rebind();
    }
```

Where `Rebind()` is defined as

```
    public void Rebind()
    {
        fileGrid.ItemsSource = _panelDataList;
        fileGrid.SelectedItem = _panelDataList.FirstOrDefault();
        fileGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

and the grid appears correctly correctly, with the row corresponding to `panelData` removed.

**The Problem**

However, if I sort the grid by any columns and then call `DeleteAndRebind(panelData)` the DataGrid still contains the item that I deleted, even though `_panelDataList` doesn't.

**Question**

Why doesn't the `DataGrid` display the updated _`panelDataList` when I sort the grid and then delete an item from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, there is no need to detach or rebind data source collections. Once you have data bound a data collection property to an `ItemsSource` property, then you should leave the `ItemsSource` property and the control alone.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionProperty}" ... />
```

All data manipulations should be done on the collection itself. So to change the collection, you just do this:

```
CollectionProperty = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>();
CollectionProperty.FillWithData(); // An imaginary data access method
```

To remove an item from the collection, you just do this:

```
CollectionProperty.Remove(CollectionProperty.ElementAt(indexOfItemToRemove));
```

To add an item to the collection, you just do this:

```
CollectionProperty.Add(new YourDataType());
```